# What are FFmpeg Video/Audio Stream parameters in order

Tags: ffmpeg

Sometime a video stream looks like this:

```
Video: h264 (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, smpte170m), 640x360, 935 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 30k tbn, 60 tbc (default)
```

Sometimes it is different:

```
Video: flv1, yuv420p, 320x240, 512 kb/s, 15 fps, 15 tbr, 1k tbn
```

Or:

```
Video: h264 (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1280x720 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 2195 kb/s, 23.98 fps, 23.98 tbr, 24k tbn, 47.95 tbc (default)
```

Output looks different based on video properties.

I'm trying to create a `java` class to get this properties separately. like `getBitrate` , `getFPS` , `getAudioSampleRate` , ...

Currently I'm using `ffprobe` in my app for just getting media info. So this way I can disable this extra option and lower app size.

For this I need to know **`Video`** and **`Audio`** stream all parameters and their order, .

I didn't find any docs, So can you help me with this?

You can see what I've done in here:
https://github.com/symphonyrecords/FFmpegUtils

Answer (score 1):

As you said, the output will change depending on the streams themselves. This is because ffmpeg contains many different encoders and decoders which each have their own way of doing things. Also different stream formats may not have the same features as each other and necessitate displaying different kinds of information to describe the streams. So there is no set order. Whats more, is future changes in format specifications or even features of ffmpeg may change the order.

Instead of trying to parse a one-line output with unpredictable content like that you should look at the [`-of` flag](https://ffmpeg.org/ffprobe.html#Writers) for ffprobe. This lets you select between different output formats for ffprobe, including several different formats that are machine readable (cvs, ini, json, xml...).

Comment: `no set order` --> the order is set but which attributes are reported depends on their presence and the loglevel.

Comment: @Gyan do you know this sets with default log level ?

Comment: The order is not set. Even if it was set between different encoders/decoders... which it's not... there's no guarantee it will remain the same between versions of ffmpeg. Again, for the use case, using the `-of` flag to get a machine readable format is the correct approach. It eliminates the need to know the order all together.

Comment: @CliffArmstrong I'm using compiled ffmpeg version in android system, which will give you separate `ffprobe` and `ffmpeg` file each one about `20MB`(depending on version) for each CPU architecture. It means 40MB app size for a single arch `eg: x86 , arm ...` support. And this is only if I'm not using any other support libraries and resources.

Comment: @CliffArmstrong - most of the data in the readouts shown by the OP is gathered from codecpar (and avctx), populated by the decoder but *is not assembled and printed by them* but by lavf utility code which has a set order.

Comment: @Gyan Even if that's true across all versions of ffmpeg that have ever been made and ever will be made... using ffprobe is still the better option as it can give easily machine parseable output in well documented formats such as JSON, INI, CSV, and more. And, to my knowledge, the order used by lavf is simply a matter of developer preference... and as such could easily change in later version. To my knowledge there is no published standard for the order used by lavf. So no... the order itself is not set. It just happens to be consistent within a given version of ffmpeg.

Comment: You're changing goalposts. The order isn't dependent on the stream format or codec. ffmpeg is an open source volunteer project so the whole architecture could change between versions. In practice, change is slow. ffprobe is more robust but that wasn't the subject of my correction.